# How do VLIW processors deal with variable-time operations?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

The concept of a very long instruction word CPU architecture is straightforward enough; as summarized on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word

> one VLIW instruction encodes multiple operations, at least one operation for each execution unit of a device. For example, if a VLIW device has five execution units, then a VLIW instruction for the device has five operation fields, each field specifying what operation should be done on that corresponding execution unit. To accommodate these operation fields, VLIW instructions are usually at least 64 bits wide, and far wider on some architectures.

It's clear how this works if every operation takes one cycle, which ALU operations very well may do.

But I have not been able to find any mention of what happens when some operations take multiple cycles. Take a simple case where there are three execution units, add, multiply and load. Say add and multiply take one cycle each. The first instruction specifies one of each operation...

But load can take anywhere from a couple of cycles to a couple of hundred, depending on whether it hits cache or must go all the way to main memory. So what happens then? The add and multiply will be done, but the load is still in progress. If the CPU proceeds to the second, third etc instruction, it must keep track of an ever-increasing backlog of pending loads, negating the VLIW selling point of not having to spend any hardware resources on bookkeeping. If it waits until all operations in the current instruction are done, the add and multiply units will be sitting idle when they could have been proceeding with useful work (and would have, in an out of order processor).

How is this dealt with in actual VLIW CPUs?

For a more concrete example, suppose the operations we want to perform are:

```
r1 += r2, r10 = [r11]
r1 += r3
r1 += r4
r1 += r5
```

The subsequent additions won't fit in the first big instruction, and need to be in separate big instructions anyway because they are dependent on previous additions. But they are all independent of the load. Does putting them in subsequent big instructions, cause the CPU to think they depend on the load, thereby causing them to stall until the load is done?

Comment: You can issue instructions that are independent of the existing load. If there is a dependence, then we stall. This would happen in an out-of-order core as well, if there is a dependent instruction waiting on a load then we stall. Out-of-order will "figure out" the available Instruction-Level-Parallelism (ILP) in a program using its HW resources, whereas in VLIW the compiler finds the available ILP and packs parallel instructions (independent) in a big instruction for execution. Because they both exploit ILP, they will have better performance over in-order processers.

Comment: @instinct71 Instructions independent of the load, that are in the *current* big instruction, can be executed without waiting for it, sure. But what happens if there are more instructions that are independent of the load, than will fit in one big instruction? What if some of them are dependent on other arithmetic instructions (so that they need to go in a later big instruction) but independent of the load?

Comment: If there are big-instructions that are not dependent on earlier big-instructions, then we can execute otherwise we have to stall. It is the compiler's job to make sure that the processor sees independent chunks of big instructions. RAW hazards will stall both out-of-order and VLIW. Typically, VLIW works well with programs that have high ILP (and where we can statically uncover such ILP).

Comment: @instinct71 But what if there are further arithmetic instructions that depend on earlier arithmetic instructions but do not depend on the load? Example added to question text.

Comment: My understanding is that the big-instruction stalls if any of the instructions cannot be scheduled. (E.g.; see slide-4 at https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep548/06au/lectures/vLIW.pdf) Of course, in the trivial example that you mention the compiler should have the smarts to fit all the adds into one big-instruction and let the load be in another big-instruction.

Comment: @instinct71 That is informative, thanks! But in the example I mentioned, the adds cannot go into one big instruction because though they do not depend on the load, they depend on each other! So this would seem to be a case where even if the compiler knows everything, VLIW cannot perform as well as an out of order CPU.

Comment: My bad. Yes, in your example the adds have RAW dependencies and are not completely independent. However, modern compiler techniques like "Reduction parallelization" can help with some parallelization of your example. That's basically the compiler using register renaming to generate independent instructions that it can pack in VLIW instruction.

Comment: @instinct71: using multiple accumulators isn't "register renaming" or a software analogue of it.  It's taking advantage of the operation being associative to create parallelism by doing operations in a different order (creating different temporaries).  In this case, on this small scale, we can create instruction-level parallelism.  (As opposed to turning data parallelism into SIMD or thread-level parallelism).

Comment: @instinct71: The software / static-scheduling equivalent of register renaming is [software pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining).  Register renaming doesn't help with RAW dependencies; unrolling loops with multiple accumulators does.  (Or re-associating non-loops to do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the correction. Yes, in "reduction parallelization" we are leveraging the associative nature of sum-reduction to generate independent instructions. A smart compiler will convert the above example to: (step 1) r2 = r2 + r3;  r4 = r4 + r5; (step 2) r2 = r2 + r4; (step 3) r1 = r1 + r2; There is no need to have new register names for outputs in step 1.